The scratch org is not ready yet (Status = New)
After running the command: sfdx org create scratch -duration-days 30 --wait 30 --username myusername@domain.com the connection times out after a while and the following error is printed:
The scratch org did not complete within your wait time
Resume scratch org creation by running "sf org resume scratch --job-id 2SRVN00000062aAAAA"

After 30 min, I run the suggested command and I get:
The scratch org is not ready yet (Status = New).

How do I provision a new scratch org without a time out?
